# Java - Convert decimal to binary - Integer - Recursive function

Tags: java, binary, decimal

Hey I'm really trying to convert decimal int to binary int, without succes.

Please help me.

And I don't want to make it 'System.out.println()' becuase I've already done it.

THANKS!

`I need recursive function that gets decimal int and return binary int

```
public static void decToBin(int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        return ;
    decToBin(number / 2);
    System.out.print(number % 2);
}
```

That it what I've done...

When I'm trying to get string:

```
public static String decToBin(int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        return "";
    return new Integer(number % 2).toString() + new Integer(decToBin(number / 2)).toString();
}
```

Error...

Comment: Please show us what you've attempted.

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Do you get some errors/incorrect results? Or are you just asking us to rewrite it into something else which doesn't use `System.out.println`?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be string or int... Look my edit again please.

Comment: Why do you need recursion?

Comment: Do you have to use `String` as result? `StringBuilder` would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String decToBin(int number) {
    if(number == 0)
        return "";
    return new Integer(number % 2).toString() + new Integer(decToBin(number / 2)).toString();
}
```

This approach has few flaws.

- First you can't use `""` as argument of `new Integer("")` because `""` holds no value, so you will see NumberFormatException.
- Other problem is order of generating result. `number % 2` should be placed *after* result of `decToBin(number / 2)`, just like you are doing it in your first example, where you are printing it after recursive `decToBin` call

  ```
  decToBin(number / 2);
  System.out.print(number % 2);
  ```
- Lastly in your return statement you are creating new string, so to generate `"100101"` you will generate `""` `"1"` `"01"` `"101"` `0101"` `"00101"` and then finally "`100101"`. To avoid it use `StringBuilder` and its `append` method.

Comment: This converts a binary integer, not a decimal number.

Comment: @EJP Hello. Could you clarify your comment? I am not saying you are wrong but I am not sure what you mean. From what I see question is about creating binary representation of *integer* provided in decimal system (I am not sure if OP wants to return String or int here so didn't focus on that). Also this answer wasn't meant to provide working solution (since it is clearly homework question about recursion) but to point few mistakes which OP made in his code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but for the sake of reference and giving a correct answer, this is what you would need to do:

```
public static String dec2Bin(int num) {

    String result = ((num % 2 == 0) ? "0" : "1");

    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return result;
    }

    return dec2Bin(num/2) + result;
}
```

Comment: This converts a binary integer, not a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void intToBinary(int num) {

    if (num < 2) {
        System.out.print(num);
        return;
    } else {
        intToBinary(num / 2);
        intToBinary(num % 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: This converts a binary integer, not a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

class Binary{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: The code example is nice, but no clarification as to what it does.  Should explain the answer (really, `Integer.toBinaryString(n)` is what the author wants I think).